# Why are my multicolumn headings only contained in the rightmost column?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

When using multicolumn, there is a problem that instead of the first row's headings spanning multiple columns, they appear to be only contained in the rightmost column of the multicolumn (see image below). I am wondering can someone help me here please. Everything I have tried hasn't worked. An reprex of the table I am creating is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-4.5em}

%\titlepic{\includegraphics{../figures/CSO_Logo.png}}
\title{Electoral Division Profile - \Sexpr{ED}}
%\date{\vspace{-5ex}}
\date{Census 2022}
\author{CSO, Ireland  (http://www.cso.ie)}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{1.7cm}}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lTTTTTTT}
  \hline
\textbf{Age Group} & \textbf{Total Population} &\multicolumn{2}{T}{\textbf{Population with any disability}} & \multicolumn{2}{T}{\textbf{Population with a disability to a great extent }} & \multicolumn{2}{T}{\textbf{Population with a disability to some extent}}   \\ 
 & & \emph{\textbf{Total}} & \emph{\textbf{\%}} & \emph{\textbf{Total}} & \emph{\textbf{\%}} & \emph{\textbf{Total}} & \emph{\textbf{\%}} \\
  \hline
  \emph{\textbf{Females}} & & & & & \\
  0 - 14 years  & 1.0 &  1.0 &  1.0 &  1.0 &  1.0 & 1.0 &  1.0\\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that I define a new column type with "\newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{1.7cm}}" which is used in the table and may be affecting things.

Thank you
[image]

Comment: you have specified your columns as `T`  so 1.7cm wide but you also specified your spanning text as T so it covers both columns but is again only 1.7cm wide. You could make your spanning column `2*1.7cm+2\tabcolsep` wide or simpler  just use natural lengths for the main column entry such as `r` or nmber aligned columns using dcolumn or siunitx, andthen use a nested tabular for the headings which will again be set natural length.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a few changes in your table. First of all to avoid long columns, I would split the current headings with a common expression *Population with disabilities* and then indicate extents in the other row.

Then, I would add `siunitx` package to format numbers in your table. With `S` column, you can centre everything within a column while keeping numbers aligned and formatted. Note, non-numeric cells under `S`-type column (`siunitx`) must be guarded within curly braces `{}`.

Finally, `booktabs` package adds custom rules and a convenient macro `\addlinespce` to increase space between row.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!tbh]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{r S[table-format=5] *3{S[table-format=3] S[table-format=2.1]}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Age}}
    & {\textbf{Population}}
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Population with disabilities}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Group}}
    &
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{any}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{great extent }}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{some extent}} \\
    \cmidrule(l{-2pt}r){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
    &
    & {\emph{\textbf{Total}}}
    & {\emph{\textbf{\%}}}
    & {\emph{\textbf{Total}}}
    & {\emph{\textbf{\%}}}
    & {\emph{\textbf{Total}}}
    & {\emph{\textbf{\%}}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{8}{l}{\emph{\textbf{Females}}} \\
     0 - 14 & 12345 &  67 & 89.0 & 123 & 45.6 &  78 & 12.3 \\
    15 - 29 &  7890 & 123 & 45.6 & 789 & 12.3 & 567 & 78.9 \\ 
    30 - 59 & 12345 & 234 & 56.7 & 890 & 12.3 &  45 & 67.8 \\ \addlinespace 
    \multicolumn{8}{l}{\emph{\textbf{Males}}} \\
     0 - 14 & 12345 &  67 & 89.0 & 123 & 45.6 &  78 & 12.3 \\ 
    15 - 29 &  7890 & 123 & 45.6 & 789 & 12.3 & 567 & 78.9 \\ 
    30 - 59 & 12345 & 234 & 56.7 & 890 & 12.3 &  45 & 67.8 \\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you:)